# Localhost xampp connection with codeigniter using mssql database error as Invalid object name 'ci_sessions'

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, adb-drivers

I have completed all steps to connect mssql with xampp localhost.
When I run code on localhost error were encountered as follows :

> Error Number: 42S02/208

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ci_sessions'.

SELECT "data" FROM "ci_sessions" WHERE "id" = 'ca4680ccaa1d99c9a97e4a4a8d639f7f2b9e374e'

from comment

```
$active_group = 'default'; 
$query_builder = TRUE; 
$db['default'] = array( 
'dsn'   => '', 
'hostname' => 'MSSQLSERVER', 
'username' => '', 
'password' => '', 
'database' => 'travell', 
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv', 
'dbprefix' => '', 
'pconnect' => FALSE, 
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'), 
'cache_on' => FALSE, 
'cachedir' => '', 
'char_set' => 'utf8', 
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci', 
'swap_pre' => '', 
'encrypt' => FALSE, 
'compress' => FALSE, 
'stricton' => FALSE, 
'failover' => array(), 
'save_queries' => TRUE 
);
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: show what you code

Comment: make sure the extension is loaded for the driver.  Check  phpinfo().  And in your `php.ini` make sure you have this extension `extension=php_mssql.dll`

Comment: You need to have windows mssql drivers installed in your php folder

Comment: $active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'MSQLSERVER',
 'username' => '',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'travell',
 'dbdriver' => 'pdo_sqlsrv,
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);         This is my database.php file

Comment: I have added extension as well as mssql driver

Comment: check error log of xampp once .. did you check ?

Comment: Yes I have checked it shows server certificate does not include an id which matches the server name

Comment: can you tell me how to load database library in autoload.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 42S02/208

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ci_sessions'.

for above error of connectivity between MSSQL 2016, Codeigniter and Xampp (PHP 7.0) check the name given to the 'ci_sessions' table created in MSSQL database and give the same name in a config.php file where table_name was mentioned for the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss db username, if options of phpmyadmin is default try username set to 'root'

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
```

Comment: I have tried hostname as localhost but it shows same error.